# Orchid rehabilitation (wrinkled leaves, one root)

Tags: orchids

Please help!! I desperately want to revive my orchid! I got a phalaenopsis orchid as a gift and I love him but I'm in over my head! This is my first orchid. Also it was just from a grocery store so the care instructions were minimal & the soil turned out to be the wrong kind and suffocated his roots. He was in bloom and healthy, then lost the bloom, then his leaves got wrinkled. I did research and repotted him, discovering during the process that the soil was suffocating the roots and all but one had died. He then got a sort of mildew on his root, (I think I packed the orchid mix too tightly) so after more research I put him hovering over distilled water with tannins to encourage root growth. He didn't like that, the root had that fuzzy white mildew again, so now he's hovering over plain water.
I live in Toronto, it's spring currently. Hes about a foot from a west facing window.
Please help me help Orcchie (his bloom looks like orecchiette pasta)! Thank you :)

Comment: Can you add a picture of the plant?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, unfortunately phalaenopsis orchids are prone to root rot, especially when it is cool and dark in winter.
Make sure it gets an hour of direct sunshine.

There are a couple of things you can do:

1. Cut away all the mildew.
2. Make sure the cuts dried.
3. Place the plant on top of orchid soil (just some bark) and keep it dry.
4. Spray the leaves with water regularly.
5. Wait until new roots grow.